# Replace ruby slice content with other content from same record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following call is needed to generate javascript for a third party library.

```
@items = Item.where('id IN (?) AND  type_id = ?', @all_valid_items, 1).all
@records = @items.map{|a| a.slice('brand', 'producer', 'title')}
```

The following is a model method to generate a desired string that should be generated in lieu of the `title` attribute data alone.

```
def title_text
  "#{title}<br />#{main_text}"    
end
```

However extending that logic to the slice method as

```
@records = @items.map{|a| a.slice('brand', 'producer').merge({'title' => a.title_text.join})}
```

returns `undefined method 'title_text' for #<Item:`  as when using

```
@records = @items.map{|a| a.slice('brand', 'producer').merge({'title' => a.values_at('title','main_text').join})}
```

`a.values_at` returns `undefined method 'values_at' for #<Item:`

What is the proper syntax to generate the modified string?

Comment: Where is this method defined? is it in Item model(assuming items are of that model's objects). Also please clarify how items is generated so we are sure what is type of each item and items collection. Lastly, also include full error message, not partial

Comment: question edited.

Comment: Are you sure this method is in item class and public, make sure it was not defined in a private context. Otherwise i dont see any reason for it to not work. You should also try in rails console with something like `Item.first.title_text`.

Comment: the string will render when calling     `@records = @items.map{|a| a.slice('brand', 'producer', 'title_text')}`  so the method works.  The problem is slice will the output the string `title_text`rather than `title`which the javascript is expecting.

Comment: You still haven't clarified where the `title_text` method is defined. What file and class is the line `def title_text` inside of?

Comment: @JordanRunning  title_text is defined in class Item (`item.rb`)

Comment: If your code is as you described in Item Model this should work.  
`@items.map{ |a| a.slice(:brand, :producer, :title).merge(title: a.title_text) }`
Tested it in my console.

Comment: @Archer That is the correct syntax! as a side matter, having an HTML tag in there `merge(title: raw(a.title_text))` is an undefined method and usually only used in views.  How would it best be handled? in model or controller?

Comment: @Jerome Mark it as HTML safe. [`a.title_text.html_safe`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-html_safe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code for the merging your data:

```rb
@items.map{ |a| a.slice(:brand, :producer, :title).merge(title: a.title_text.html_safe) }
```

`.html_safe` is the equivalent to `raw(some_string)` and you can use it in the model or controller.